# displaying sum of a database value - PHP

Tags: php

Hi I need to get the sum of the database field sbstart. I changed the code to SUM(sbstart) but doesn't seems to be a valid move. How can I display the sum? Thanks.

```
        <?php


$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$db = 'regional_data';
@ $db = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db);

if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    die('The connection to the database could not be established.');
}
$query = "SELECT SUM(sbstart) FROM newchk WHERE dist_chk ='$distUsr'";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);

while ($recS = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

echo ($recS['sbstart']);    
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
$query = "SELECT SUM(sbstart) FROM newchk WHERE dist_chk ='$distUsr'";
```

To (Use alias)

```
$query = "SELECT SUM(sbstart) as sub FROM newchk WHERE dist_chk ='$distUsr'";
```

Then

```
you doesn't need while loop because it return only one result.

$recS = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
echo $recS['sub'];
```

Comment: SUM() has nothing to do with while(loops). It returns a single result from the database for any number of matches :) So ditch your while loop. Replace while with an if as it happens once anyways.

Comment: @Claudrian Yes and I guess its much faster as well. Thanks for the highlight!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use either `mysqli_fetch_assoc` instead of `mysql_fetch_array`, or you need to do `echo $recS[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$query = "SELECT SUM(sbstart) FROM newchk WHERE dist_chk ='$distUsr'";
```

to

```
$query = "SELECT SUM(sbstart) AS sum FROM newchk WHERE dist_chk ='$distUsr'";
```

and change

```
echo ($recS['sbstart']);
```

to

```
echo ($recS['sum']);
```